# How can I run in background command, which runs only in foreground?

Tags: laravel, cron, schedule, laravel-scheduler

I have the command, which works like `php artisan queue:listen`. And it can't work in background in common, but I have to add it to cron tab, but it does not work there. Does it possible to do something like `php artisan schedule:run` ? The most imortant that when I interrupt this command, all functionalyty will stop. What do I have to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has his own cron. First of all, you should add Laravel cron to Linux system cron

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

then you can add your commands to Laravel cron.

Laravel crons lives inside a file /app/Console/Kernel.php
the are should be inside function
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
for example

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
      $schedule->command('emails:send Taylor --force')->cron('* * * * *');
    }
```

But if you want your command run as a system process not as a cron you should use supervisors program(supervisord) or you can create for  PHP command file a systemd service file and then run as if the are a normal systemd service and even manage this service through monit program in with web interface as well

Comment: Thank you, I think I will try to use Supervisor because it does not work in cron.

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to use 
Supervisord and the are some information about it in the Laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: I tried to do it through Supervisor and it works well. Thank you. But if I change something in DB, it does not restart. Actually, I put autorestart into config. What can I do? Because when I change values of settings it will not change too while I do not use supervisorctl restart

Answer (score 0):

If your php script is a process it means that the constructor method of class  runs only ones when you start your script and if you red db data in the constructor that data in the script would be stale
Your process script should be process something like this

```
class OpenOrders extends Command
{
     public function __construct()
     {
            parent::__construct();
     }

     public function handle()
     {
        $this->initTicker();
        $this->updateBalances();

        //the Process
        while (true) {

            //this is the right place to read DB data
            $this->getAllOptions();

            $this->openOrders = $this->getOpenOrders();

            
        }

        return 0;
    }
 }
```